# How can i toggle the visibility of a textview which is dynamically created linked to a button which is created dynamically?

Tags: java, android, textview

```
                            @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                        final JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                                        final String content = jsonObject.getString("content");
                                        final LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.lay);
                                        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                                        btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        TextView txt = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                        final TextView txt1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                        final ImageView img = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        txt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

txt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                                            txt1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                                            img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

```
                                        txt.setId(i);
                                        txt.setText(title + '\n');    
                                        txt.setGravity(1);
                                        img.setId(i);
                                        txt1.setId(i);
                                        txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                txt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                txt1.setText(content);
                                                try {
                                                    Picasso.get().load(jsonObject.getString("icon")).into(img);
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                        txt.setWidth(900);
                                        txt1.setWidth(900);
                                        linearLayout.addView(img);
                                        linearLayout.addView(txt);
                                        linearLayout.addView(txt1);
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    textView.setText("That didn't work!");
                    Log.d("error", error.toString());
                }
            });
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

Comment: use setvisibility(View.GONE) to hide the textview

Answer (score 0):

You just need a clicklistener for the dynamic button then set the visibility of the dynamic text to txt.setVisibility(View.GONE); if you want it gone and 
txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); if you want it visible. If you are trying to toggle it just make a boolean that keeps track of state. You need something like this:

```
Boolean state = false;
if(state){
    txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    state = false;
else{
    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    state = true;
}
```

Comment: suppose i have got three buttons showing the title only and i want only a the text view linked to that particular button to be displayed and if i have clicked on the other created buttons the text view once displayed with that button to be removed..then what to do?

Comment: it is all about using a click listener for each button and only manipulating the visibility of the buttons/txt from the corresponding listeners. If you need to keep track of what state it is use a boolean.

Comment: well i saw that using a list view would be better than using dynamic text views bro..thanks a ton btw